# Pull in mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I have a `ListField(DictField)` which contains items like -

```
{'user_id': '12345', 'timestamp' : 'datetime-object'}
```

In mongoengine, how can I remove elements from the List queried on user_id. For instance, I want to remove entries with a particular user_id. I tried the following -

```
update_one(pull__notes__user_id = '12345')
```

Here `notes` is the name of the collection.

This statement returns `1` but it does not remove the element from the List. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two ways of doing this:

A) Match the element exactly:

```
class Simple(Document):
    x = ListField()

Simple.drop_collection()
Simple(x=[{'hello': 'world'}, {'mongo': 'db'}]).save()

// Pull the dict
Simple.objects.update_one(pull__x={'mongo': 'db'})
```

B) Match part of the element.
   Use the [positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The$positionaloperator) to match the element and unsets it.

```
class Simple(Document):
    x = ListField()

Simple.drop_collection()
Simple(x=[{'hello': 'world'}, {'mongo': 'db'}]).save()

// Set to None
Simple.objects.update_one(unset__x__S__mongo='db')
// Pull None
Simple.objects.update_one(pull__x=None)
```

Comment: I can't use the first option. The second alternative gives me the following error - AttributeError: 'BaseField' object has no attribute 'lookup_member'

Comment: Can you provide your schema and then I should be able to do a test :)

Comment: Also what version of mongoengine?